# How to use gap.barplot when all values are greater than the gap in R?

Tags: r

I'm fairly confused as to how `gap.barplot`, from package `plotrix` works as the following piece of code returns an error

```
 gap.barplot( c(3.5, 3, 4, 5), gap = c(1, 3), ytics = c(0, 1, 4, 5) )
```

The error given is:

> Error in rect(xtics[y < gap[1]] - halfwidth, botgap, xtics[y < gap[1]] +  : 
>   cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates

The example given in the R documentation is

```
 twogrp <- c(rnorm(10)+4,rnorm(10)+20)
 gap.barplot(twogrp, gap = c(8,16), ytics = c(3,6,17,20))
```

Which works fine. The only difference is that my example has all bars above the break. You may ask, well why not just use a different ylim, the answer to that is that sometimes you really want to emphasise to the reader that the axis doesn't start at zero, visually, (you want the reader to be able to grasp both relative and absolute differences)

Comment: Can you get by with just adding a 0 to the vector you plot:  `c(0, 3.5, 3, 4, 5)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trick the plot as suggested by @Jota, and then adjust `xlim` and `xaxlab`:

```
library(plotrix)
gap.barplot(c(0, 3.5, 3, 4, 5), gap = c(1, 3), ytics = c(0, 1, 4, 5), 
         xlim=c(1.5,5.5), xaxlab = c(-1,1:4), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
```

Obviously `xlim` and `xaxlab` were adjusted manually, but that's usually the case with gap plots. `xaxs` and `yaxs` remove the spaces between the first tick and the axis. It's necessary specially for x < 0, to hide the trick-bar.

[image]

Instead of changing `xaxs`, you can take advantage of `halfwidth` (which as expected requires manual adjustment), and also separate the bars:

```
gap.barplot(c(0, 3.5, 3, 4, 5), gap = c(1, 3), ytics = c(0, 1, 4, 5), 
             xlim=c(1.6,5.4), xaxlab = c(-1,1:4), halfwidth = 0.4)
```

[image]